# Is there a way to install Ubuntu next to Windows 10 , using Encryption and LVM without disk erasing?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, encryption, lvm

So I tried to install Ubuntu next to Windows by graphic installation wizard, but I can't mark 2nd and 3rd option without marking 1st one...

- Erase disk and install Ubuntu
- Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security
- Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation

Is there a way to not to "Erase disk" and install Ubuntu with LVM and encrypted next to Windows 10 with graphic methods?

edit :

First I've made 2 partitions ,then i installed Windows, then i tried to install Ubuntu but as You got standard graphic installation options I marked "Install Ubuntu alongside windows" and that effects with leaving "-Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" and "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" options UNAVAILABLE. Only when instead of installing alongside i mark "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" i'am able to use those two options i'am interested to. Please help :)

Comment: I highly suggest you read the install guide - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

You need to create an unallocated partition and then can install Ubuntu into that space.